# Como eu posso substituir o "String.isEmpty()" no Java?

Tags: java, android, string

Tenho o seguinte:

```
    data = new Json().execute(URL).get();

    System.out.println(data);

    if (!data.isEmpty()) { //erro neste data.isEmpty
```

Tenho um erro:

> tem um erro: Call requires API level 9 (current min is 8): java.lang.String#isEmpty

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O jeito mais fácil de saber se uma *string* é vazia é verificar se seu tamanho é zero, que é o que o Java faz no método [`isEmpty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty--) no Java padrão, então também pode fazer isso:

```
if (data.length() != 0)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/Nothing.java).

Comment: As APIs do Android inferiores à 9 têm essa limitação mesmo, elas não implementam o `isEmpty()`, não sei bem por quê.

Comment: @Piovezan nem tinha pensado que poderia ser Android. Ainda assim é louco, porque isto existe desde a 6.

Answer (score 7):

Assumindo que voce esta no android:

1. Voce pode usar [TextUtils.isEmpty(string)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)
2. String.trim().equals("") também funciona

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294270/using-string-isempty-with-actionbarsherlock)

Comment: Existe uma diferença entre "empty" string ( string vazia)  e "blank string" (não sei uma boa tradução, mas seria uma string composta de caracteres de espaços).  Assim `"".isEmpty() == true`, mas `"     ".isEmpty() == false`.  Usando `trim()` você pode transformar uma blank string em um empty string, introduzindo um erro.

Answer (score 3):

Considerando que data seja uma String você pode fazer assim:

```
      if(!"".equals(data))
```

Comment: Teria que fazer pelo menos um `data.trim()`. Se `data` for `" "` (tiver um espaço) a sua checagem não funcionará.

Comment: @renan na verdade esta resposta está mais certa que a do Felipe (na verdade erro do Ascorbin no SO), pelo menos em parte dela, afinal se der um `trim()` é porque a *string* tinha um espaço e não estava vazia.

Comment: Outro motivo pra essa ser mais aconselhada é que ela nunca vai dar nullpointer.

Answer (score -2):

Pode ser assim:

if (str.equals("") {
    //comandos aqui
}